# ERROR ReferenceError: "d3 is not defined"

Tags: angular, d3.js

I need to display a gauge chart, the component in compiled successfully,
but the chart is not displayed, and it shows a console error.

> ERROR ReferenceError: "d3 is not defined" gauge
>
> http://localhost:4200/main.js:129:17drawhttp://localhost:4200/main.js:245:26ngOnInithttp://localhost:4200/main.js:109:9checkAndUpdateDirectiveInlinehttp://localhost:4200/vendor.js:40334:9checkAndUpdateNodeInlinehttp://localhost:4200/vendor.js:41598:20checkAndUpdateNodehttp://localhost:4200/vendor.js:41560:16prodCheckAndUpdateNodehttp://localhost:4200/vendor.js:42100:5View_AppComponent_Host_0ng:///AppModule/AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:8:5updateDirectiveshttp://localhost:4200/vendor.js:41889:63checkAndUpdateViewhttp://localhost:4200/vendor.js:41542:5detectChangeshttp://localhost:4200/vendor.js:39929:13tickhttp://localhost:4200/vendor.js:35665:58tickhttp://localhost:4200/vendor.js:35665:13_loadComponenthttp://localhost:4200/vendor.js:35699:9bootstraphttp://localhost:4200/vendor.js:35641:9_moduleDoBootstraphttp://localhost:4200/vendor.js:35442:74_moduleDoBootstraphttp://localhost:4200/vendor.js:35442:13bootstrapModuleFactoryhttp://localhost:4200/vendor.js:35408:21invokehttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2710:17onInvokehttp://localhost:4200/vendor.js:34908:24invokehttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2709:17runhttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2460:24scheduleResolveOrRejecthttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3194:29invokeTaskhttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2743:17onInvokeTaskhttp://localhost:4200/vendor.js:34899:24invokeTaskhttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2742:17runTaskhttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2510:28drainMicroTaskQueuehttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2917:25

Comment: Please share your code. Probably you need install d3 library using npm.

Comment: try on top of the component.. declare var d3;

Comment: it's declared already

Comment: @VishnuNair stackblitz url is working fine no error in console

Comment: Please publish your code, where you use d3

Comment: Yeah, I took the code from this link. But its showing the error in my localhost console

Comment: @KamilNaja https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xf9w3b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Hi @VishnuNair witch version are you using of angular?

Comment: @KrishnaRathore Angular 2. I'm new to Angular. Just started

Comment: Plz share your package.json and let me do with you.

Comment: Updated. Angular 6 is used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `import d3 from 'd3';`

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/error-referenceerror-d3-is-not-defined?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**npm install d3 --save**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import d3 from 'd3';

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {
    gaugemap: any = {};
    ngOnInit(){
        console.log(d3)
    }
}
```

**[Refrence URL](https://medium.com/netscape/visualizing-data-with-angular-and-d3-209dde784aeb)**

Comment: Now showing 
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(3,8): error TS1192: Module '"/home/globalit/my-new-gauge/node_modules/@types/d3/index"' has no default export.

Comment: npm install d3 --save

Comment: ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(93,25): error TS2362: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.
src/app/app.component.ts(97,25): error TS2362: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.

Comment: use fat arrow function like `=>`   ------------

startAngle((d:any, i)=> {
            var ratio = d * i;
            return deg2rad(config.minAngle + (ratio * range));
          })

Answer (score 0):

Try in angular.json

> "scripts": [
>                 "./node_modules/d3/dist/d3.min.js"
>               ]

And in your components

```
 import * as d3 from "d3";
```

Then you will be able to call it correctly in your component and also while you are debugging without having any error